# Error during git push

Tags: git, git-push

I'm a novice and when I do `git push`, I'm getting the following error:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:danreardon/mg_app.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Can anybody help me with this issue?

Comment: Try stashing your local changes with `git stash`, then pull in any changes from your remote repo with `git pull <branch>`. Then, do a `git pop` to get your local changes back and try youe `git push` again.

Comment: Thank you!

git stash - no local changes to save

git pull <branch> - I've only been working on the master branch and it says

fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: what does `git status` show?

Comment: `git pull --rebase` *normally* fits better in this case (avoiding merging), but I wouldn't recommend using it until understanding what *rebasing* is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do git pull from your origin to local master and do merge and after that you could do push.

```
 git pull origin master
```

You may have to merge the changes, if needed.

If the remote repository has changes which are not yet updated in local master, you couldn't be able push your new changes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate the help. Everything is now working!

Answer (score 0):

This will be because your local version of master is out of date, call git pull and resolve the conflicts. Be careful to *only* resolve the conflicts.

Resolving conflicts works as normal, remember to git add each file you update and then do a git commit. Only try to commit when you've resolved *all* the conflicts. You'll get instructions on how to abort the commit if things go wrong.

If you're working on a branch most of the time this will make your life much easier (even if the branch doesn't exist in the remote repository.